# Margins in Memoir Document Class

Tags: margins

I am using the `memoir` document class to make a 6"x9" two-sided book. I want to be able to print it out on 8.5"x11" paper and then cut it with a paper cutter (a little wasteful I know).

This is what I have so far. I can't figure out how to get the text block to move where I want it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,showtrims]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\settypeblocksize{6.75in}{4.25in}{*}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `\checkandfixthelayout`, you get `Class memoir Error: \spinemargin (97.26999pt) and/or \textwidth (307.14749pt)
 and/or \foremargin (148.02501pt) are too large for \paperwidth (433.62pt) by 118.8225pt.`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the margins to something which will fit. For example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,showtrims]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\settypeblocksize{6.75in}{4.25in}{*}
\setulmargins{50pt}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.6}

\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: trim marks]

Since you haven't said where you want the text block to go, it is hard to help you with that one, but presumably only needing to trim on 2 sides is preferable, so a corner position such as this would be best.